# How to Login linkedin in android?

Tags: android, authentication, linkedin-api

I am building an android application where user will login using linkedin.

When user click on the button the default linkedin login page appear after entering the Email ID and password when I click accepted I an disable to get user details.

Below is my login code -

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLinkedin) {

        oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
                .createLinkedInOAuthService(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                        Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        System.out.println("oAuthService : " + oAuthService);

        factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(
                Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

        liToken = oAuthService
                .getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken
                .getAuthorizationUrl()));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(i);



    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {

        linkedInImport(intent);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void linkedInImport(Intent intent) {
    String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    System.out.println("liToken " + liToken);
    System.out.println("verifier " + verifier);



    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(
            liToken, verifier);
    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

    // client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");

    Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
            ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
            ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE));


    System.out.println("First Name :: " + profile.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name :: " + profile.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Head Line :: " + profile.getHeadline());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn now provides an Android development SDK to handle these situations for you more easily, that you might want to look into:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case anyone came here looking for answers...

LinkedIn has deprecated and stopped supporting their old mobile SDKs as per [this link](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates), so I've created a lightweight "unofficial" SDK for Android, you can use it from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/AbdAllahAbdElFattah13/LinkedIn-SDK-Android).

We also use it in our production apps, so it should be working fine. :)